# Ошибка при использовании транзакций

Tags: mysql, sql, yii2, transaction

Необходимо очистить данные в двух связанных таблицах

Беру пример из учебника и слегка модифицирую

```
    $transaction = $this->connection->beginTransaction();
    try {
        // $this->connection->createCommand()->truncateTable($this->sectionLangTable)->execute();
        // $this->connection->createCommand()->truncateTable($this->sectionTable)->execute();
        $this->connection->createCommand('SET foreign_key_checks = 0')->execute();
        $this->connection->createCommand('DELETE FROM '.$this->sectionLangTable)->execute();
        $this->connection->createCommand('DELETE FROM '.$this->sectionTable)->execute();
        $this->connection->createCommand('ALTER TABLE '.$this->sectionTable.' AUTO_INCREMENT=1')->execute();
        $this->connection->createCommand('SET foreign_key_checks = 1')->execute();
        $transaction->commit();
        return true;
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $error = $e->getMessage();
        $transaction->rollBack();
        return false;
    }
```

В итоге вылетает с исключением 

`Syntax error or access violation: 1305 SAVEPOINT LEVEL1 does not exist 
The SQL being executed was: RELEASE SAVEPOINT LEVEL1`

Исключение возникает в момент commit или rollback.

Сначала пробовал то что закоменчено - тоже самое.

В гугле в основном результаты с Codeception и его конфигам.
Потом идут разговоры о том, что не поддерживает mysql вложенные транзакции.

Но судя по логам транзакция там одна.

`2018-02-27 12:04:05 [-][-][-][trace][yii\base\Application::bootstrap] Bootstrap with yii\log\Dispatcher
2018-02-27 12:04:05 [-][-][-][trace][yii\base\Module::getModule] Loading module: gii
2018-02-27 12:04:05 [-][-][-][trace][yii\base\Application::bootstrap] Bootstrap with yii\gii\Module::bootstrap()
2018-02-27 12:04:05 [-][-][-][trace][yii\base\Controller::runAction] Route to run: migrate/up
2018-02-27 12:04:05 [-][-][-][trace][yii\base\InlineAction::runWithParams] Running action: yii\console\controllers\MigrateController::actionUp()
2018-02-27 12:04:05 [-][-][-][trace][yii\db\Transaction::begin] Begin transaction
2018-02-27 12:04:05 [-][-][-][trace][yii\db\Transaction::begin] Set savepoint 1
    in D:\www\edusites\htdocs\common\components\sitemap\repository\SitemapRepository.php:156
    in D:\www\edusites\htdocs\console\components\migration\handlers\InitialInfoHandler.php:32
    in D:\www\edusites\htdocs\console\migrations\data\m180214_092839_menu_initial.php:18
2018-02-27 12:04:05 [-][-][-][trace][yii\db\Transaction::commit] Release savepoint 1
    in D:\www\edusites\htdocs\common\components\sitemap\repository\SitemapRepository.php:165
    in D:\www\edusites\htdocs\console\components\migration\handlers\InitialInfoHandler.php:32
    in D:\www\edusites\htdocs\console\migrations\data\m180214_092839_menu_initial.php:18
2018-02-27 12:04:05 [-][-][-][trace][yii\db\Transaction::rollBack] Roll back transaction
    in D:\www\edusites\htdocs\common\components\sitemap\repository\SitemapRepository.php:170
    in D:\www\edusites\htdocs\console\components\migration\handlers\InitialInfoHandler.php:32
    in D:\www\edusites\htdocs\console\migrations\data\m180214_092839_menu_initial.php:18`

Данные из таблиц тем не менее чистятся.

Прошу помощи.

P.S. Пока перечитывал пост увидел что в логе нет слова LEVEL а в тексте исключения есть. Может быть в этом беда, но это как-то странно.

P.S.2 тоже самое, но вместо удаления insert - работает хорошо.

`2018-02-27 12:24:51 [-][-][-][trace][yii\base\Application::bootstrap] Bootstrap with yii\log\Dispatcher
2018-02-27 12:24:51 [-][-][-][trace][yii\base\Module::getModule] Loading module: gii
2018-02-27 12:24:51 [-][-][-][trace][yii\base\Application::bootstrap] Bootstrap with yii\gii\Module::bootstrap()
2018-02-27 12:24:51 [-][-][-][trace][yii\base\Controller::runAction] Route to run: migrate/up
2018-02-27 12:24:51 [-][-][-][trace][yii\base\InlineAction::runWithParams] Running action: yii\console\controllers\MigrateController::actionUp()
2018-02-27 12:24:52 [-][-][-][trace][yii\db\Transaction::begin] Begin transaction
2018-02-27 12:24:52 [-][-][-][trace][yii\db\Transaction::begin] Set savepoint 1
    in D:\www\edusites\htdocs\common\components\sitemap\repository\SitemapRepository.php:155
    in D:\www\edusites\htdocs\console\components\migration\handlers\InitialInfoHandler.php:32
    in D:\www\edusites\htdocs\console\migrations\data\m180214_092839_menu_initial.php:18
2018-02-27 12:24:52 [-][-][-][trace][yii\db\Transaction::commit] Release savepoint 1
    in D:\www\edusites\htdocs\common\components\sitemap\repository\SitemapRepository.php:165
    in D:\www\edusites\htdocs\console\components\migration\handlers\InitialInfoHandler.php:32
    in D:\www\edusites\htdocs\console\migrations\data\m180214_092839_menu_initial.php:18
2018-02-27 12:24:52 [-][-][-][trace][yii\db\Transaction::commit] Commit transaction`

Comment: Добрый день. А почему бы Вам не использовать миграции?

Comment: @slo_nik я как раз их использую - они точка входа, мне далее надо будет добавлять данные с разной сложной логикой, используя репозитории других компонентов, чтобы не дублировать функционал (в миграции и компоненте)

Comment: В миграции крайне редко редактируют данные, только структуру таблиц и базы.

Comment: @slo_nik Да, я вынес этот функционал из миграции и по этой причине тоже

Comment: Ну так Вы же не редактируете данные, а просто очищаете таблицы. Зачем выносить из миграции?

Comment: @slo_nik Это малая часть того что я собираюсь делать, Далее будут инсерты, апдейты и прочее

Comment: ну так эту часть и оставить в миграции, а всё остальное(insert, update) уже в модели или контроллер.

Answer (score 1):

Ваша процедура в принципе не транзакционна. Про этот раздел мануала часто не знают, пока не наткнутся на странное поведение, но и `truncate` и `alter table`, как и другие `DDL` запросы вызывают в mysql [неявный коммит](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/implicit-commit.html).

Коммит (или `rollback`), явный или нет, моментально освобождает все объявленные `savepoint`. После этого ваш фреймворк, не учитывающий такую неожиданность, получает закономерную ошибку при работе с уже удалённым `savepoint`.

Comment: Спасибо большое за просвещение! Получается все альтеры надо вынести, оставить делити, сейчас попробую.

Comment: сейчас у меня есть серия из двух подобных операций, то есть сначала в транзакции чистится одна пара таблиц, затем в другой транзакции другая пара таблиц. И если я между транзакциями вставлю ALTER TABLE - вторая транзакция покажет туже ошибку с пойнтами. Знаете в чем дело?

Comment: Надо смотреть происходящее предметно, при том на уровне sql. Т.е. например `general_log_file` и `general_log`. Тогда будет видно что происходит.

Comment: Крутой ответ не подскажите хороший FAQ по БД или книгу (только не офф документация).